# Unit Test visibility: Account vs User Object

Tags: apex, unit-test

I just started learning the salesforce apex coding from the [link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm) and wondering why the below method can access User object but not Account object?

```
// Test method that has access to only the data it creates
// and organization setup and metadata objects.
@isTest static void testWithOwnDataAccess() {
    // This method can still access the User object.
    // This query returns the first user object.
    User u = [SELECT UserName,Email FROM User LIMIT 1]; 
    System.debug('UserName: ' + u.UserName);
    System.debug('Email: ' + u.Email);

    // Can access the test account that is created here.
    Account a = new Account(Name='Test Account');
    insert a;      
    // Access the account that was just created.
    Account insertedAcct = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account 
                            WHERE Name='Test Account'];
    System.assert(insertedAcct != null);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with V24, test classes would by default not see any existing non-setup org data. (User is a setup object, Account is not.)

This is best practice as it greatly minimizes deployment errors so test code in sandbox does not rely on a misleading set of sandbox org data that isn't present in PROD.

SFDC hasn't done a great job at documenting which SObjects are visible to V24+ testmethods but you can see some of them [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm).

The list is not complete, for example `StaticResource` is definitely visible to testmethods at V24+. As is `PartnerNetworkConnection` (used by Salesforce to Salesforce)

Answer (score 1):

The User object sometimes acts as more of a metadata component than a data component.  When Salesforce decided to "black box" test methods, it was just a decision they made to make Users still available in Test Methods.